# Weird behaviour in JSON Python library

Tags: python, json

Whenever I go to update a string in a list in JSON, I can only do it directly and not through a variable. It's best to try it out yourself. This program looks at the user input and appends it to its address if it's a new answer and the user's address is not found in the list. If the user's IP is in the list, then it just overwrites the old answer with the new one.

To replicate problem replace this line:

`data["answers_dict"]["0"][index] = new_answer + '|' +  address`
With this one:
`data_indexed =  new_answer + '|' +  address`

Why is this happening? All it is a variable swap

This is the code that works:

```
import json


new_answer = '4_div'
file_dir = 'Data/test_answers_database.json' 

with open(file_dir,'r+') as file:

        data = json.load(file)
        address = '127.0.0.1'
        answer_change = False
        
        index = 0
        for i in data["answers_dict"]["0"]:
                address_location = data["answers_dict"]["0"][index].find('|') + 1
                data_indexed = data["answers_dict"]["0"][index]
                
                if data_indexed[address_location:] == address:
                        data["answers_dict"]["0"][index] = new_answer + '|' +  address
                        answer_change = True
                
                index += 1

        if answer_change is False:
                data["answers_dict"]["0"].append(new_answer + '|' +  address)
        
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file, indent = 4)
```

The JSON file:

```json
{
    "answers_dict": {
        "0": [
            "3_div|127.0.0.1"
        ],
        "1": [],
        "2": [],
        "3": [],
        "4": [],
        "5": [],
        "6": [],
        "7": [],
        "8": []
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is not possible. You bind a str value from a list to name `data_index`. Then you bind new value. On other hand using `data["answers_dict"]["0"][index]=` is index assignment to a mutable list and works.

Comment: What causes the confusion is Call by value and Call by reference Concept.
Please read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-call-by-value-and-call-by-reference/) to see how other languages behave and then read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/) to see how python behaves in situations like this.
In one word you were writing your code in JAVA it was all good and working fine!

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? Does it make a difference if you retrieved some list from JSON? This question should be answered by extracting a [mcve], which is also why it's required here.